# Name of matrices with diagonal entries as column indexed functions of row?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, soft-question, convolution

Ok. I am aware this might seem a bit... obscure question.

Lately I have grown interested in a family of matrices

$$M_{ij} = f(i,j)$$

Example are the famous convolutional matrices constant along diagonal strips: $$M_{ij} = c_{i-j}$$

which implement convolution with filter having $\mathcal Z$-transform $$c(z) = \sum_{k=-N}^N c_kz^{k}$$

Another example of such matrix is the differentiation operator on a P space

$$M_{ij} = i\cdot \delta(i-j-1)$$

For second order differential:

$${M_{ij}}^2 = (i+1)\cdot i\cdot \delta(i-j-2)$$

Ovviamente we also have for linear combinations of higher order derivatives:

$$\sum_{n} d_n{M_{ij}}^n = \sum_{n} P_n(i)\delta(i-j-n)$$

It is easy to imagine we can save space by storing functions calculating these matrix elements whenever we need them, instead of storing the whole matrices.

For a small example for $D^2-I$ instead of storing the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}    -1    &0&     2&     0&     0&     0\\
     0&    -1&     0&     6&     0&     0&\\
     0&    0&    -1&     0&    12&     0&\\
     0&     0&     0&    -1&     0&   20&\\
     0&     0&     0&     0&    -1&     0\\
     0&     0&     0&     0&     0&    -1\\\end{bmatrix}$$

(or even bigger, could be arbitrarily big!), it would be nicer to store only three polynomials $-1,0,(x+1)x$ for example if we assume they live in $P_2$ space we could store

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and then multiply with $$ \begin{bmatrix}1\\x\\x^2\end{bmatrix}$$

We can see convolutional matrices described above will be subset with such matrix description of the following form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}c_{-N}&0&0\\\vdots&0&0\\c_N&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Only the constant terms non-zero.

Now to my question. Do matrices classified in this way have some name?

I am aware of for example Vandermonde matrices, which are not exactly the same but kind of similar as they also relate to polynomials in a related way.