# Is the set polynomial diagonal matrices equiped with matrix multiplication as operation a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, soft-question

Aloha, my dudes and dudettes.

I have grown interest in a specific type of matrices in [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3274681/name-of-matrices-with-diagonal-entries-as-column-indexed-functions-of-row). For context they do occur when expressing differential equations on coefficients for truncated power series.

In short, they are linear combination of diagonal matrices, where each diagonal is a polynomial of row index. But a new polynomial for each diagonal:

$$M_{ij} = P_{i-j}(i)$$

Two questions have popped up which could greatly improve usefulness of alternate representation of these matrices:

1. Are they closed under matrix multiplication? To me it seems they are, but I have not been able to prove it.
2. The identity matrix is one of the simplest examples in the set and if we consider matrix multplication an operation, what would be left to prove that our set of matrices is a group if we equip it with this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you imposing any degree restrictions on the polynomials $P_{i-j}(i)$? If not, then I can answer both your questions:

1. Yes, they are closed under matrix multiplication.
2. Assuming that you only take invertible such matrices, then it's a subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ if we show that it's also closed under inverses, which it is.

The reason for both answers is that your set of matrices is actually $M(n, \mathbb{R})$, the set of *all* $n \times n$ matrices.

Consider any matrix $A$. As you look over the different diagonals, you have at most $n$ points that look like $(i, a_{ij})$, and you want to find a polynomial $P_{i-j}(i)$ that goes through these points. [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) ensures that you can do this with a unique polynomial of degree at most $n-1$. You do this for each diagonal, and then your matrix (and so in fact *any* matrix) is of this form.

Note that the coefficients of the polynomials will often be much larger in magnitude than the actual entries of your matrix. So there's no real hope of saving space by storing the polynomials instead of the matrix entries unless you know a lot more about other restrictions on the form of your matrix.

Comment: You are correct, I should have imposed degree restrictions. The factor matrices having polynomials of order $n,m$ and product matrix $n+m$ or $n+m+1$ (not sure which). Since I forgot to mention this I will give you upvote anyways.

Comment: The degree restrictions for each subdiagonal can't change when you take products or else you quickly get above $n-1$ and recover all matrices as before. So instead they'd have to look like a single degree restriction, either for all polynomials, or one for each subdiagonal. But then as you can see with diagonal matrices, these restrictions won't be preserved by product.

Comment: Ok I already tried it and it works as I thought. You just need to be careful at the parts of the matrix where there is no circulation. There you will need to store a couple of extra elements which won't be captured by the polynomials. But it is as I thought with $n$,$m$ and $m+n$.

Comment: I still don't understand what your proposed set of matrices is. Let me ask you a question. What is one matrix that definitely is *not* in your set?